# Cannot resolve org.cytoscape with IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, cytoscape

I'm following the instructions here (https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape/wiki/Cytoscape-App-Ladder) in order to learn how to build a first, simple Cytoscape App, but I get in stuck at the "Setup for Cytoscape app development" step because after I imported the projects from github in IntelliJ, I obtain the following issues:

[image: IntelliJ console].

How can I resolve?

PS. I'm new to Cytoscape and Maven projects too.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this.  We just moved our repositories to a new server and didn't correctly update all of the links.  We'll try to get that fixed as soon as possible.

-- scooter